# Checking the date and time and filling the missing data

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a data file in 10 minute interval with some missing data.

```
cat << EOF > ifile.txt
2001/1/1 0:00 3
2001/1/1 0:10 32
2001/1/1 0:40 17
2001/1/1 0:50 4.402
2001/1/1 1:00 3.95
2001/1/1 1:50 1.42
2001/1/1 2:00 0.34
2001/1/1 2:10 0
2001/1/1 2:20 9
2001/1/1 2:30 57
EOF
```

If you check the above file, there are some missing data, e.g. at 0:20, 0:30 etc.

I would like to check the data with date and time from 2001/1/1 0:00 until 2001/1/1 3:00 and fill the missing data as "nan".

My script is as below.

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=" ";
    start_time = mktime("200101010000");
      end_time = mktime("200101010300");
current_minutes = 0;
}
{
    entry_time = mktime(gensub(/[:\/]/, " ", "g", $1" "$2));
    while (current_minutes < (entry_time - start_time) / 60) {
        printf "%s %02d:%02d nan\n", strftime("%Y/%m/%d", start_time), int(current_minutes / 60), current_minutes % 60;
        current_minutes += 10;
    }
    print $0;
    current_minutes += 10;
}
END {
    while (current_minutes <= (end_time - start_time) / 60) {
        printf "%s %02d:%02d nan\n", strftime("%Y/%m/%d", start_time), int(current_minutes / 60), current_minutes % 60;
        current_minutes += 10;
    }
}' ifile.txt
```

But it is not printing the missing data. It is just printing my input file.

Desired output:

```
# ofile.txt content
2001/1/1 0:00 3
2001/1/1 0:10 32
2001/1/1 0:20 nan
2001/1/1 0:30 nan
2001/1/1 0:40 17
2001/1/1 0:50 4.402
2001/1/1 1:00 3.95
2001/1/1 1:10 nan
2001/1/1 1:20 nan
2001/1/1 1:30 nan
2001/1/1 1:40 nan
2001/1/1 1:50 1.42
2001/1/1 2:00 0.34
2001/1/1 2:10 0
2001/1/1 2:20 9
2001/1/1 2:30 57
2001/1/1 2:40 nan
2001/1/1 2:50 nan
2001/1/1 3:00 nan
```

Comment: This problem only becomes interesting if your timestamps can span days and in particular days/times during a DST change so if that can happen you should update your sample input/output to include at least one such range.

Comment: With that input format, how do you know if the difference between 1:50 and 2:00 is 10 minutes or 12 hours and 10 minutes or 24 hours and 10 minutes or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below `GNU awk`(I am using `gawk4.2.1` and `gawk5.3.0`) to achieve your result:

```bash
BEGIN {
    start_time = mktime("2001 01 01 0 0 0")
    end_time = mktime("2001 01 01 3 0 0")
    # interval 600s
    interval = 10 * 60
    FS = OFS = " "
}
{
   # combines the first two fields (date and time) of the input line.
    current_time = $1 " " $2
   # timestamp for the current_time in seconds since the epoch.
    current_timestamp = mktime(gensub("/", " ", "g", $1) " " gensub(":", " ", "g", $2) " 0")
   # prints the missing timestamps with "nan" until the start_time >= current_timestamp.
    while (start_time < current_timestamp) {
        # formatting matters here. No zeros would be appended at the start suing this.
        print strftime("%Y/%-m/%-d %-H:%M", start_time), "nan"
        start_time += interval
    }
    print $0
    start_time += interval
}
# This block is executed after processing the input file. 
# It prints any remaining missing timestamps until the end_time is reached.
END {
    while (start_time <= end_time) {
        print strftime("%Y/%-m/%-d %-H:%M", start_time), "nan"
        start_time += interval
    }
}
```

*[demo here](https://replit.com/@msankrit/ObviousJoyousBaitware#main.sh)*

---

##### EDIT (h/t *[Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton)*):

If you notice In the above code I've used `%-*` for `m`, `d` and `H` inside of `strftime()` to remove the leading `0` from them. This works perfectly fine in Mac and ubuntu.<sup>***1***</sup> Now, the point to note here is this usage depends upon one of those "underlying primitives" differences between platforms since the same or equivalent code does not work on Windows 11 and cygwin or git-bash in `awk`, `perl`, or `python` (but does in `date`).

Also, though this behavior of adding a `-` to remove padding IS defined in [the GNU `date` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html):

> By default, date pads numeric fields with zeroes.  The following
> optional flags may follow '%':
>
> - (hyphen) do not pad the field

and in [the GNU libc documentation for the version of `strftime()` they provide](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Formatting-Calendar-Time.html):

> Conversion specifiers are introduced by a ‘%’ character, followed by
> an optional flag which can be one of the following. These flags are
> all GNU extensions. The first three affect only the output of numbers:
> ...
>
> - The number is not padded at all.

there is no similar documentation about it in [the `gawk` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions) or [the Linux `strftime()` platform function man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3p.html) or [the POSIX spec for `awk`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) or [the POSIX spec for the platform `strftime()` function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strftime.html) so it is undefined behavior for `awk` and YMMV on what `%-` does depending on which version of `strftime()` your platform provides.

As a result of [this issue](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2024-01/msg00027.html) being raised with the GNU awk providers, the GNU awk manual will be updated as follows:

> Similar to `printf()`, some versions of `strftime()` support the use
> of flags between the `%` and the format specification letter.  Check
> your local manpage for `strftime()` to see if it supports flags or
> not, and what they are. Be aware, however, that using any such flags
> is likely to make your script less portable to other  systems.

The above method is easier syntactic sugar to remove leading `0s` but if it is not supported on the platform you are using then see the below solution (manually removing them) which works platform-agnostically.

```bash
BEGIN {
   # Same as above
{
    # ...rest
        print strftime("%Y", start_time) "/" strftime("%m", start_time) + 0 "/" strftime("%d", start_time) + 0, strftime("%H", start_time) + 0 ":" strftime("%M", start_time), "nan"
       # ... rest
}
END {
      # ... rest
        print strftime("%Y", start_time) "/" strftime("%m", start_time) + 0 "/" strftime("%d", start_time) + 0, strftime("%H", start_time) + 0 ":" strftime("%M", start_time), "nan"
}
```

*[demo here](https://ideone.com/NvZAME)*

---

##### References and further reading:

1. [Test runs on Mac](https://imgur.com/a/YtgCkA6)
2. [Issue raised by Ed Morton with gawk providers](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2024-01/msg00027.html)
3. [`gawk` manual Time Functions section (includes `strftime()` synopsis)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions)
4. [POSIX spec for `awk` (POSIX awk has no `strftime()` so just background reading)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)
5. [Linux `strftime()` platform function man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3p.html)
6. [POSIX spec for the platform `strftime()` function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strftime.html)
7. [GNU `date` man page (defines using `%-` in this way)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html)
8. [GNU libc documentation for the version of `strftime()` they provide (defines using `%-` in this way)](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Formatting-Calendar-Time.html)
9. [Related question "How to represent date format in '2015120' in Linux shell?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/180008/133219)